# Function in view takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given during redirection

Tags: python, django

So I have the following code in my view for redirection

**View file:**

```
def signIn(request):
    ....
    ....
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin_page")
```

Now the `admin_page` is mapped in the url as such

```
url(r'(admin_page)$',"adminApp.views.show_admin_page"),
```

Now this is what my view file looks like

```
def show_admin_page(request):
    return render(request, 'hayyan.html')
```

As a result i get the error

```
show_admin_page() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Why am i getting this ? What other method is being passed to the `show_admin_page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the parentheses in this url:

```
url(r'(admin_page)$',"adminApp.views.show_admin_page"),
```

As, you can see in the [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#example) here:

> To capture a value from the URL, just put parenthesis around it.

In the url pattern you used parentheses around `admin_page`, so the view you created expect two arguments `request` and `captured_value`:

```
def show_admin_page(request, captured_value):
    ...
```

Since, you don't need to capture anything from the URL, you don't need the captured groups. You can simply have following:

```
url(r'admin_page$',"adminApp.views.show_admin_page"),
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it could you tell me why my view was expecting to parameters and by simply changing the regex it got fixed ?

Comment: Please look at the updated answer for more explanation.

Comment: Yep thanks for clearing that up- Marked as answer after timer